# Why do I not get my boxplots properly aligned when using 'varwidth=TRUE' in geom_boxplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I am trying to make a plot in which I show per individual (`ID`) the mean depths (`meanDepth`) distribution through boxplots. I want that the width of my boxplots is relative to the sample size, but at the same time, I want to increase, in general, the width of all my boxplots since there is too much blank space among boxplots. I tried this:

```
Plot <- ggplot(data = Data) + 
  aes(x=ID, y=meanDepth, col=Site) + 
  geom_boxplot(size=1.75, varwidth = TRUE, position = position_dodge2(preserve = "single"), width=1.2) + 
  labs(y="\n Mean depth (m)") + 
  coord_capped_cart(bottom="both",left="both") +
  theme_bw() + 
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size=3.5))) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", limits = c(55, 0), breaks = round(seq(0,55,55/4),1))

Plot
```

[image]

I have observed than if I used bigger values than 1 for `width`, the boxplots move along the X-axis obtaining what you see. Why is that?

How can I increase the width of my boxplots at the same time than I do their width proportional to their sample size?